# If a regular graph of order 3 is planar how many faces should it have?

Tags: graph-theory

I have reasoned in this way. Since it has to be regular and planar with 3 vertices we would get a triangle. So it should have an inner face and an outer face. Is that correct or I have misunderstood the question that seems very simple to me?

Comment: The triangle graph is of order $2$: every *vertex* has $2$ connections. Since there are multiple possible planar regular graphs of order $3$, I assume an expression of $F$ in terms of $V$ is desired?

Comment: @SmileyCraft now that I think about it you are right in believing that the answer to this question is a generic expression depending on the number of vertices and their order. By thinking quickly, correct me if I'm wrong, we could use the classic Euler formula adapted to our context: $Faces = (degree*3) - 1$.

Comment: You are correct that Euler's formula is applicable, however the formula you got is incorrect. Maybe it helps to consider some examples. Such as the tetrahedron, the cube and the dodecahedron.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have time to edit my comment. I re-read your comment. What do you mean by order? I mean the number of vertices of the graph and by degree the number of edges of a vertex. So a triangle is for me a regular graph of degree 2 and order 3 (three vertices).

Comment: Maybe not entirely justified indeed, but I assumed the order to be the degree of every vertex, since we are talking about regular graphs.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify the terminology used. In the context in which this question was posed, we refer to a graph with $3$ vertices and since it is also regular these vertices will all have the same degree. Since the latter is not specified you are right in saying that I should come to a generic expression for one degree $>=2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87386/discussion-between-pcnf-and-smileycraft).

Comment: If order refers to the amount of nodes, then I actually agree with your solution in the OP. The only pitfall could be that the graph may have no edges, or the graph might not necessarily be simple, but I doubt that is what the question is aiming at.

Answer (score 3):

Euler's formula is $$V-E+F=2\tag{1}$$

The handshaking lemma says that twice the number of edges is the sum of the vertex degrees.  In this case$$E={3V\over2}\tag{2}$$  Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together gives $$F={V\over2}+2$$